# Erro Undefined index: user ao enviar um formulário POST

Tags: php, mysql

### Html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="encomenda_apagar.php" method="POST">
 <br><br>
 <label class="sr-only" for="inputHelpBlock"></label>
 <b>INSIRA O SEU USERNAME:</b> <br><br>
 <input type="text" name="user">
 <br>
 <center><input type="submit" value="Eliminar"></center>
 <br>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

### PHP

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function myFunction(a) {
    alert(a);
}

</script>

<?php

ini_set ('default_charset','utf-8');

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd_calcadocharme");

$id=$_GET['user'];

$sql="DELETE FROM cliente WHERE user='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($link)){
    echo "<script> myFunction('Cliente elimado com sucesso'); </script>";
        header('refresh:0 ; url=escrever.html');
} elseif ($result && !mysqli_affected_rows($link)){
    echo "<script> myFunction('Esse cliente nao existe !'); </script>";
        header('refresh:0 ; url=escrever.html');
} elseif (!$result){
    echo "<script> myFunction('Erro na query!'); </script>";
        header('refresh:0 ; url=escrever.html');
}

?>
```

> Erros: Notice: Undefined index: user in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\PAPBRUNO\PAPBRUNO\encomenda_apagar.php on line 15

E não entendo o porque .

Quando vou a tentar apagar alguém que não exista APARECE a mensagem de "erro na query" e DEVIA APARECER "Esse cliente não existe"
E mesmo quando meto alguém que existe , não apaga

Comment: O seu método(entenda-se formulário) esta enviando via `POST`, e você esta tentando recuperar o `user` via `GET`

Comment: Bem deu, mas mesmo eu quando tento apagar alguém que existe base de dados, aparece a mensagem de Esse cliente nao existe

Comment: Existe mais de um erro no seu código kkk
Concatenação de strings via PHP você necessita utilizar o ponto(.)

Comment: @Odacil não somos um fórum, não edite a pergunta, adicione uma resposta a sua própria pergunta clicando em "Responder" (fica no formulário abaixo). Faça o tour para entender como funciona o StackOverflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio sugiro formalizar a sua resposta.

Comment: @Odacil também notei que você tem várias perguntas com respostas, mas você não aceitou nenhuma como "Correta/Certa", após entender como funciona o StackOVerflow recomendo marcar as respostas que considerar correta as suas perguntas, isto incentiva os demais usuários a responderem, pois vale pontos (você também ganha ponto se aceitar uma resposta)

Comment: -- "Vejo SQL Injection" -- "Com que frequência?" --"Todo o tempo". Você está pegando parametro de $_GET sem nem tratar esse inteiro. Do jeito que está, seu código permite deletar mais do que só o usuário desejado. Pelo menos use `$id= (int) $_GET['user'];`

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 3):

Seu formulário está usando `method="POST"`, basta alterar `$id=$_GET['user'];` para `$id=$_POST['user'];`

Recomendo também que evite passar variáveis diretamente para a sua query, no caso como está usando `mysqli` então você pode tentar usar [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), exemplo:

```
$id = $_POST['user'];

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bd_calcadocharme');

if (false === $link) {
    printf('Erro de conexão: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'DELETE FROM cliente WHERE user=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);

/* Executa a query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

//Fecha stmt
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

//Fecha conexão
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 2):

Igual Matheus Velloso falou, mude o

```
<form action="encomenda_apagar.php" method="POST">
```

Para

```
<form action="encomenda_apagar.php" method="GET">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu form é no parâmetro POST e você ta esperando, segundo o seu script, um paramentro $_GET. Por isso está dando um indefinido.